# Finding the Distribution $XY$ when $X\sim U(1,N-1)$ and $Y\sim U(1,N-X)$ when N is a constant integer

Tags: statistics

How would I go about finding the distribution for the following problem?

Let $X\sim U(1,N-1)$ and $Y\sim U(1,N-X)$. Let $N$ be an integer. Find $W$ when

\begin{equation}
W = XY
\end{equation}

Note: $U$ is the discrete uniform distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write
$$\eqalign{\mathbb{P}(W=k)&=\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}\mathbb{P}(W=k,X=d)\cr
&=\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}\mathbb{P}(XY=k,X=d)\cr
&=\sum_{d=1}^{N-1}\mathbb{P}(Y=k/d,X=d)\cr
&=\sum_{d|k,d<N}\mathbb{P}(Y=k/d,X=d)\cr
&=\sum_{d|k,d+k/d<N}\mathbb{P}(Y=k/d,X=d)\cr
&=\sum_{d|k,d+k/d<N}\mathbb{P}(Y=k/d|X=d)\mathbb{P}(X=d)\cr
&=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{d|k,d+k/d<N}\frac{1}{N-d}
}$$
However I do not think that this sum can be simplified anymore.

Comment: Isn't the one inside the final sum $1/(N-1)$ as well? The final result should be $1/(N-1)^2$ times the number of divisors of $k$ which is a known function.

Comment: Ok the sum is conditioned on annoying things and it's probably unknown but still that should be $N-1$ and not $N-d$ I guess.

Comment: @Maffred, No, given $(X=d) $ then $Y$ is uniformly distributed in $\{1,\ldots,N-d\}$ please read the question.

Comment: Uhm I was sure they were independent xD Nicely done then!